# Arranging morse code alphabetically in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var morseCode = {
  "A": ".-",
  "B": "-...",
  "C": "-.-.",
  "D": "-..",
  "E": ".",
  "F": "..-.",
  "G": "--.",
  "H": "....",
  "I": "..",
  "J": ".---",
  "K": "-.-",
  "L": ".-..",
  "M": "--",
  "N": "-.",
  "O": "---",
  "P": ".--.",
  "Q": "--.-",
  "R": ".-.",
  "S": "...",
  "T": "-",
  "U": "..-",
  "W": ".--",
  "X": "-..-",
  "Y": "-.--",
  "Z": "--.."
}

function longestMorseCodeWords(word)
{
 var convertWord = word.toUpperCase();
 convertWord = convertWord.split("");
 for (var i = 0 ; i<convertWord.length ; i++)
  {
   convertWord[i] = morseCode[convertWord[i]];
  }
 convertWord = convertWord.join(" ");
 return convertWord

}

longestMorseCodeWords('a');
```

I am able to translate a string to morse code but what I really am trying to do is to translate a set of arrays into morse code.

For example, longestMorseCodeWords(['hello','apple','ball'])

Also, it should be ordered by the length of their Morse Code equivalent in ascending order. If the length of Morse Code is equal, order the words alphabetically hence, it should show ['ball', 'apple','hello'] . I'm stuck :/ I don't know where to start.

Comment: There's no need for `convertWord.split("")`. You can access characters of a string with `[i]` notation.

Comment: Split this into two functions. One function converts a single string to Morse code. Then you can call that function using `.map()` to convert an array. And finally you can sort the result by length of the Morse code.

Comment: If you want to return the original text, you can make it an array of objects like `{text: "hello", morse: ".... . .-.. .-.. ---"}`

Comment: You can definitely do more research on your own here, looks like you cane straight to SO.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the code of a string and use it for sorting.

This approach takes [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) which take an iterable, like a string, takes single letters as array nad performs a mapping with the following function. This function gets the code for a character. At the end the code is joined with a string to separate the morse code character.

```js
function getMorseCode(word) {
    return Array.from(word.toUpperCase(), c => morseCode[c]).join(' ');
}

var morseCode = { A: ".-", B: "-...", C: "-.-.", D: "-..", E: ".", F: "..-.", G: "--.", H: "....", I: "..", J: ".---", K: "-.-", L: ".-..", M: "--", N: "-.", O: "---", P: ".--.", Q: "--.-", R: ".-.", S: "...", T: "-", U: "..-", W: ".--", X: "-..-", Y: "-.--", Z: "--.." };

console.log(getMorseCode('sos'));
console.log(['hello','apple','ball'].map(getMorseCode));
console.log(['hello','apple','ball'].sort((a, b) => getMorseCode(a).length- getMorseCode(b).length));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: when i want to post something, your answer is already there -))

Answer (score 0):

Extending objects are always possible, if not better :)

```
var morseCode = {
    "A": ".-",
    "B": "-...",
    "C": "-.-.",
    "D": "-..",
    "E": ".",
    "F": "..-.",
    "G": "--.",
    "H": "....",
    "I": "..",
    "J": ".---",
    "K": "-.-",
    "L": ".-..",
    "M": "--",
    "N": "-.",
    "O": "---",
    "P": ".--.",
    "Q": "--.-",
    "R": ".-.",
    "S": "...",
    "T": "-",
    "U": "..-",
    "W": ".--",
    "X": "-..-",
    "Y": "-.--",
    "Z": "--.."
  }

String.prototype.toMorse = function() {
  return this.replace(/a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z/gi, function(char){
    return morseCode[char.toUpperCase()];
  });
}

String.prototype.morseLength = function() {
  return this.toMorse().length;
}

["ball", "apple", "hello"].sort(function(e1, e2){
  return e1.morseLength() - e2.morseLength();
});
```